# Why can't I access self?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am new to swift and I am having trouble with return types. I have a class/ type method which should return an instance of the same class. As I understand, it is not the native Swift behaviour to return instancetypes. Following is an example code of what I did:

```
public class CustomView: UIView {

  class func createCustomView(arguments: Array) -> Self {
    return createCustomViewInternal(arguments)
  }

  private class func createCustomViewInternal<T>(arguments: Array) -> T {

    return CustomView(frame: CGRectZero).createCustomViewInstance(arguments) as! T
  }

  private func createCustomViewInstance(arguments: Array) -> Self {

    //Do customization here.
    ---> return self
  }
```

I cannot access self at the marked point. Also if I try to add a constraint programatically, I get an compiler error "Cannot convert value of type 'Self' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'". Where did I go wrong?

returning instancetype would have been much simpler in Objective-C. Is there a simpler way to return self?

Comment: Why not just `-> CustomView` ?

Comment: @Thilo I was trying to write a generic method on the lines of an Obj-C design language. Anyways, does it make a difference? By the time self is accessed, we wouldn't even have returned anything. I just tried it, but makes no difference :(

Comment: what is the purpose of the class functions and the generic parameter, why don't you just have some simple init functions ?

Comment: An `Array` is a generic type, but your code missing `Array`'s `Element` declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to subclass from UIView.

You could use the concrete class instead of Self. Self would only be relevant for subclassing, when you do not want to override. **Using CustomView instead of Self makes many things easier.**

You could use one class method instead of two.

You could override a init method, instead of this customizing method.

But if you **really** need it that way, here is a working solution:

```
import UIKit

public class CustomView: UIView {
    public var property: Int = 0

    public required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public class func createCustomView(param: Int) -> Self {
        return createCustomViewInternal(param)
    }

    private class func createCustomViewInternal(param: Int) -> Self {
        return self.init(frame: CGRectZero).createCustomViewInstance(param)
    }

    private func createCustomViewInstance(param: Int) -> Self {
        self.property = param

        return self
    }
}
```

Side note:

*Arguments are the concrete given values. When you use the abstract value in a method, it is called parameters.*